# Is $(a^s\pmod{n})^k = a^{sk}\pmod{n}$?

Tags: number-theory

Is $(a^s\pmod{n})^k = a^{sk}\pmod{n}$?
And if it is, how come?

I've thought about it and this is the only thing that makes sense (for now).

Comment: $a^smodn$ is not a number..

Comment: Yes, because that's how arithmetic works in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.  $\overline a\cdot\overline b=\overline{a\cdot b}$

Comment: @JDrinas No, but it is a class of numbers that can be multiplied.  That's multiplication in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Gregory Grant Thanks,I think I get it now..

Comment: I'm thinking $(a^s+qn)^k = a^{sk} + (...the rest of the things...)n$. Is this right?

Comment: @Superman That's correct

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $x≡a^smodn$ and $y≡a^smodn$,then $xy≡a^{2s}modn$ Try for $x=y$..

(if $x≡a^smodn$,then $x^k≡a^{sk}modn$)

Comment: Tips: you can use `\equiv` for the symbol $\equiv$, and `\pmod n` for expressions like $a^s \equiv x \pmod n$. For a complicated modulus, use braces, e.g. `a^{s+2} \equiv a^2a^s \pmod {2n}` for $a^{s+2} \equiv a^2a^s \pmod {2n}$.

Comment: @ pjs36 Thank you pjs!..I am still learning this :-)